# on demand refresh of Knowledge One sidebar component

Tags: knowledge, service-cloud-console

Wondering if anyone knows how to force a refresh of the Knowledge One Console Component from within the console itself, as a result of a button click for example ?

Any suggestions most appreciated!

Cheers

** UPDATE ** The requirement arose when a custom VF page was in use for case detail rendering within the service console view, and updates to the context case record were resulting in partial view refreshes and not a complete context record view refresh. This in turn then meant the standard knowledge sidebar widget would not be refreshed automatically as happens in the standard console view.  To add to the challenge, key information ideally used in the knowledge search was stored as child record information, not on the case record itself, so could not contribute to category pre-filtering.

An example of how this was playing out was that if the subject field or a field on a child record that could influence the pre-filtering capabilities of the knowledge widget changed, the knowledge widget would not refresh to reflect (and leverage) these updates.

Problem was thus - could we manually request a sidebar widget refresh once the partial view update was complete, or did we need to go a custom knowledge sidebar ? The answer in the end was went a custom knowledge widget where on page load the controller would aggregate the required pre-filter ing information.  This only part solved the challenge because in the end we still didnt find a way to request/force a refresh to the sidebar from the context record, without having to do a complete tab refresh.

Hope this clarifies what this was about...

Answer (score 1):

Eventually went the custom sidebar route...

Comment: Hey CloudHugger, could you add some detail about what the route involves? As it is this answer would still leave future visitors hunting around for information.

Comment: Apologies for any confusion caused. I have updated the question to provide more context and ultimately the direction taken to address the issue.